# using jTable data to jTextField using jComboBox list

Tags: java, swing

I have a `jComboBox` which supposedly contains data from a `jTable`. 
My combobox lists are

- Archer
- Knight
- Rogue
- Mage

What I want is if a Knight is chosen from the combobox I want the data of Knight from the `jTable` to be imported to a specific `jTextField`.

I have a `jTextField1` as STR,
`jTextField2` as AGI,
and so on..

How do I code these instructions?

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"Archer",  new Double(5.0),  new Double(12.0),  new Double(6.0),  new Double(3.0),  new Double(4.0)},
            {"Knight",  new Double(14.0),  new Double(4.0),  new Double(10.0),  new Double(1.0),  new Double(1.0)},
            {"Rogue",  new Double(6.0),  new Double(18.0),  new Double(3.0),  new Double(4.0),  new Double(5.0)},
            {"Mage",  new Double(3.0),  new Double(4.0),  new Double(4.0),  new Double(18.0),  new Double(17.0)}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Specializations", "STR", "AGI", "CON", "INT", "WIS"
        }
```

Comment: where is the data stored? in the table or in the combobox?

Comment: the data is stored in the table. i want it to be transferred to a jtextfield when  the option is selected from combobox. lets say i select knight from my combobox, i want the data of knight from the table transferred to a jtextfield

Comment: can you give a visual example how the data is stored in the table?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hKJTd60.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data in the combobox are in the same order as in jTable:

```
int selectedIndex = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
    Object valueAt0 = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(selectedIndex, 0);
    Object valueAt1 = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(selectedIndex, 1);
    jTextField1.setText("" + valueAt0 + " " + valueAt1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make a Heroe Class,  to create your heroes (Wrap the values in a class and override the toString() method.)

```
class ComboItem
{
private String key;
private String value;

public ComboItem(String key, String value)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return key;
}

public String getKey()
{
    return key;
}

public String getValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

Add the ComboItem to your comboBox.

```
comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("Visible String 1", "Value 1"));
comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("Visible String 2", "Value 2"));
comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("Visible String 3", "Value 3"));
```

Whenever you get the selected item.

```
Object item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
String value = ((ComboItem)item).getValue();
```